# Unresolved External Symbol for Class?

Tags: c++, types, external, symbols

I'm working on something personal as an exercise with classes. As background, I basically just want to make a class for players of a board game, to keep track of the order of their turns based on some simple calculations using their stats.

My Player class includes this constructor line:

```
Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int diceRoll);
```

Its private data is as follows:

```
int Dex, Mod, Lvl;
string name;
```

I have the following in my main function, and have included the iostream and string libraries.

```
int rollD; //Will be input by the user
Player Derek("Derek", 2, 0, 6, rollD);
//... etc.
```

The error that the compiler throws is precisely this:

Initiative.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Player::Player(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,int,int,int,int)" (??0Player@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HHHH@Z) referenced in function _main

I am using Visual Studio 2012. From what I can tell, it's taking issue with the syntax of my constructor call, though I believe it to be correct.

Can anyone help me out? I've looked through the other threads with "External Symbol" errors, but I don't appear to have done the things that caused their errors, as my code is very simple.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** New error. I've changed the name of my private members in the class to be more readily identifiable (mDex, for example). So I have the following:

```
Player::Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int diceRoll) {
              mName = name;
      mDex = Dex; 
      mMod = Mod;
      mLvl = Lvl;
}
```

Now my error is in the string name parameter. It seems to define name as the type, not the variable, and says I am not allowed to use type name.

**EDIT 2:** Full code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player {
  public:
Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int diceRoll);

int calcInitiative(int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl);
int sortInitiative(int Init);

int diceRoll;

  private:

  int mDex, mMod, mLvl;
  string mName;
};

int main() {
int rollD; //To be given by the user later.

Player::Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int diceRoll) {
mName(name), mDex(Dex), mMod(Mod), mLvl(Lvl);
}

Player Derek("Derek", 2, 0, 6, rollD);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `but I don't appear to have done the things that caused their errors, as my code is very simple` you didn't implement the method, did you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Update with the edit: You should use constructor initializer lists to initialize your members.

Comment: I see that it is a cleaner, more compact approach but it does not resolve my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement the constructor for `Player`.

Defined inside class:

```
class Player{
  //...other stuff
  Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int diceRoll):
          name_(name), Dex_(Dex), Mod_(Mod), Lv1_(Lv1), diceRoll_(diceRoll){}
};
//^^^Assume name_ and others are your member variables
```

Defined outside class:

```
Player::Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int diceRoll):
          name_(name), Dex_(Dex), Mod_(Mod), Lv1_(Lv1), diceRoll_(diceRoll)
{}
```

Otherwise, the compiler cannot find the definition of your constructor.

Comment: Ooohhh, silly me! Right, so if I don't have the constructor implemented outside the class, of course it would not be defined for the main function. Thanks!

Comment: @user2395694 Yes, Note that it is OK to define inside class.

Comment: Huh. Now it is telling me in my outside the class function definition that I'm not allowed to use 'type name'.

I have as a parameter for the constructor 

string name

So, why is it giving me this error?

Comment: Done. The error is for the string name parameter, it seems to think name is the type instead of the parameter.

Comment: @user2395694 have you included `string` header? You'd prefer using member initialization list.

Comment: #include <string> is there at the top of my code, yes. I also briefly tried #include <cstring> to see if there was any change. No luck.

Comment: @user2395694, `<cstring>` is for C string functions. And are you indicating that `string` resides in `std`?

Comment: I just wondered if it would make a difference. No, simply that my first two lines are including the iostream and string libraries appropriately.

Comment: @user2395694 you should use std::string, since string is in namesapce std

Comment: I also have a 

using namespace std;

line. Wouldn't that absolve me from having to do that every time I wanted to use a string? I was probably mistaken about the utility of including <string>, but I am also using the std namespace.

Comment: @user2395694 weird. You have other codes not shown? The error may be in some other places.

Comment: I'll post the full thing for clarity, I guess. I would've initially, but I thought just focusing on the parts giving my initial error would be best. I'll update the original post.